# How the ResponseEntity class should be parametrized in the GlobalExceptionHandler

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a SonarQube error for the following class, which I don't know how to parameterize.

What kind of object do I need to return in line `return new ResponseEntity(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    // handling specific exception
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidFieldException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Exception> resourceNotFoundHandling(InvalidFieldException exception, WebRequest request){
        ErrorDetails errorDetails =
                new ErrorDetails(new Date(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Argument Validation failed", exception.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // handling global exception
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Exception> globalExceptionHandling(Exception exception, WebRequest request){
        ErrorDetails errorDetails =
                new ErrorDetails(new Date(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Global Exception", exception.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ResponseEntity` is a parameterized type. You should provide a type argument. The type argument should probably be `ErrorDetails`, but then you'd have to change your return type to match that.

Comment: Your image is broken. Please post the error/warning message as text instead though.

Comment: Provide the parametrized type for this generic.. This is the error messsage

Answer (score 1):

The parametrized type must be the same as the passed object in the constructor. You use `ErrorDetails` so you have to use it:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    // handling specific exception
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidFieldException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> resourceNotFoundHandling(InvalidFieldException exception, WebRequest request){
        ErrorDetails errorDetails =
                new ErrorDetails(new Date(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Argument Validation failed", exception.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // handling global exception
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> globalExceptionHandling(Exception exception, WebRequest request){
        ErrorDetails errorDetails =
                new ErrorDetails(new Date(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Global Exception", exception.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```